# How to solve error ';' expected when used gnuplot 4.2

Tags: gnuplot

I used one of software that needs to be used gnuplot to plot figure, but I first know the gnuplot and have some problem.

I follows this web site [gnuplot demo script: transparent.dem](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/transparent.html) to plot secend figure used the scripts:

`set style fill transparent solid 0.5 noborder
 set title "Transparent filled curves"
 replot`

But I get error `';' expected` when ipnut `set style fill transparent solid 0.5 noborder`. My gnuplot version is 4.2 and then I cheak the [gnuplot-4.2.6.pdf](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuplot/files/gnuplot/4.2.6/gnuplot-4.2.6.pdf/download) find folows message:

`set style fill {empty | solid {<density>} | pattern {<n>}}
{border {<linetype>} | noborder}`

It's seem that there is no `transparent` parameter in 4.2 version. My question is how to modify it can get follows figure?

Thakns.

[image]

Comment: You already found out that 4.2 doesn't support transparent filling, so you must upgrade...

Comment: Whether there are other ways besides upgrading?

Comment: No, there is no workaround. Transparency for filled areas was introduced with version 4.4.0 seven years ago.

Comment: Ok, Thanks. I got it.